# How does spreadtab know it is a number?

Tags: glossaries, calculations

Using `spreadtab` with `glossaries` I define a glossary entry A with a field `user1=12`. Now, if I call this field in a `spreadtab` table with `\glsentryuseri{A}`, `spreadtab` does not recognize it as a number. Could I convince `spreadtab` somehow that it is a number?

Comment: Would you please add a minimal example?

Comment: @egreg:  `\newglossaryentry{A}{name={foo}, user1=12}` and then something like `\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{ll}} \glsentryuseri{A}&1\\ \end{spreadtab}`

Comment: Please, add the code for a minimal compilable example to your question; there should be also the names of the packages to load

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [spreadtab](http://ctan.org/pkg/spreadtab) chokes on macros with arguments. To get around this, you can just store the value inside a macro without an argument by using

```
\newcommand{\glsentryuseriA}{\glsentryuseri{A}}
```

and it will work. Here's the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{A}{name={foo}, user1=12}
\newcommand{\glsentryuseriA}{\glsentryuseri{A}}

\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{ll}} \glsentryuseriA&[-1,0]*2\\ \end{spreadtab}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, but the main idea was to use arguments. If spreadtab does not like those I have to look for an another solution.

Comment: @leh: try contacting the author of `spreadtab`. I have seen him on this site, so probably he just hasn't seen your question.